# Facebook reveal tab if users liked page it goes to registration form and if registered reveal another page

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-like

I am looking to do a reveal tab. When a user goes to a fan page tab it will show a specific tab. When the user likes the page it will reveal a registration form. If  user is also registered it will reveal another tab(that is basically after it is liked and registered). Is there a way to access if a user has registered on my page and also liked? Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep possible.  Google "Facebook Fan Gate" and you will find many code examples of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;

if ($session) {
try {
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
}
}


$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

// decode the data
$sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
$data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
return null;
}

// check sig
$expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
return null;
}

return $data;
} 

function base64_url_decode($input) {
return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

$data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], "APP_SECRET");


if ($data['page']['liked']){

//SHOW REGISTRATION FORM

}else{

//SHOW NO FAN PAGE

}
```

Comment: yes but this will only check if the page is liked or not. What i need is to check if its liked to show the registration form and is liked and register to show something else. If the user has not liked(which basically means he hasnt registered) to show something else.